# How to properly manipulate data from AngularJS in Jade template in Express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, pug

I am working around with the data from AngularJS. The difficulty is with the Jade template. Before, I directly parsed the data to the view using res.render() function and I can do something like this

This is the backend (app.js)

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   Article.find({}).sort({'created':-1}).limit(limit).exec(function(err, data) {
        res.render('index', {articles: data});
   });
});
```

And here's the Jade template to handle the data

```
each article, i in articles
    .blog
        h2= article.title
        .article-info.clearfix
            .author
                .author-img
                    img(src='./images/profile.jpg')
                .author-name
                    p #{article.author}
            .post-date
                p
                    i.fa.fa-calendar.fa-md 
                    |   #{moment(new Date(article.created)).format('MMMM Do, YYYY')}
        .img-container
            img(src='./images/#{article.image}')
        .text
            p= textManager.cutWords(striptags(article.content), 100)
        .toolbar.clearfix
            a.button.transparent.setleft(type='button', href='/#{article.reference}') READ ARTICLE
            a.button.setright.facebook-share-like
                i.fa.fa-facebook.fa-lg
                |   LIKE
            a.button.setright.facebook-share-like(ng-click='getAttribute();')
                i.fa.fa-facebook.fa-lg
                |   SHARE
```

You can see that I call some functions such as moment.js (using moment(date).format('YYYYMMMMDD')) to handle the date display and my custom functions named cutWords to handle the content display. With this method, everything works really fine. But when I changed to use AngularJS to handle all the data via AJAX and iterate using ng-repeat. The app won't work. Here is the current code

```
.blogs(ng-controller='articleController')
    .blog(ng-repeat='article in articles')
        h2 {{article.title}}
        .article-info.clearfix
            .author
                .author-img
                    img(src='./images/profile.jpg')
                .author-name
                    p {{article.author}}
            .post-date
                p
                    i.fa.fa-calendar.fa-md 
                    |    moment({{article.created}}).format('MMMM Do, YYYY')
        .img-container
            img(src="./images/{{article.image}}")
        .text
            p textManager.cutWords(striptags({{article.content}}), 100)
        .toolbar.clearfix
            a.button.transparent.setleft(type='button', href="/{{article.reference}}") READ ARTICLE
            a.button.setright.facebook-share-like
                i.fa.fa-facebook.fa-lg
                |   LIKE
            a.button.setright.facebook-share-like(ng-click='getAttribute();')
                i.fa.fa-facebook.fa-lg
                |   SHARE
```

With the latter code, nothing works and shows error. I don't know why. I think there's must be something that I did wrong with the Jade template when calling the function (Please see when I call moment() and textManager.cutWords() functions)

Anyone knows how to solve the problem.

Comment: Angular supports date formatting like this `{{ article.created | date:'MM.dd.yyyy' }}` see docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date  and you should use angular way for cutWords. Something like `$scope.article.content = textManager.cutWords(striptags($scope.article.content), 100)`

Comment: Thank you Molda. The date now displays properly.